# Converting a Dataease 4.23 DQL database into a SQL database

Tags: sql, dql

So I have a DataEase DOS 4.23 database, which I have full access to open and look at, and I'm looking to see if I can somehow convert this into a MSSQL or PGSQL (or any modern SQL, really) database.  I've looked through this software, and I can't seem to find any sort of export function.  I've found some documents that say to upgrade the system to 5.x, which has an export function, but I've had trouble locating an installer for DataEase 5.x.

Is there any known way to programmatically export the DQL to a more modern format?  Even CSV is acceptable to me at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!  Just had to use the wayback machine to find a program called Datagrab that some guy wrote in 2002, which only worked on XP and prior machines, so I created a VMware WinXP installation, transferred Datagrab and the database files to that machine, and was able to successfully transform the database tables into CSV files with only a few hundred errors (easily solved)!

Answer (score 0):

Solved this with a program DataGrab.
In the link there is a newer software called ConvPlus, which has more features.

Both programs were tested on Windows 7 SP1 and have done their work

http://www.meltonisl.com/software.html